# How do I get a button to change a variable based on another variable?

Tags: python-3.x, user-interface, tkinter

I am making a clicker game and need to find how to make a variable change based on another variable, Here is the code:

```
from tkinter import *


Apples = 0
APS = 0
AppleClickVal = 1


# create root window
root = Tk()
 
# root window title and dimension
root.title("Apple Clicker")
# Set geometry(widthxheight)
root.geometry('350x200')
 
# adding a label to the root window
lbl = Label(root, text = "Click the apple?")
lbl.grid()
 
# function to display text when
# button is clicked
def clicked():
    lbl.configure(text = "You just gained " + str(AppleClickVal) + " Apple! You now have " + str(Apples) + " apples!")
    Apples =+ AppleClickVal
    return Apples
 
# button widget with red color text
# inside
btn = Button(root, text = "Click me" ,
             fg = "red", command=clicked)
# set Button grid
btn.grid(column=1, row=0)
 
# Execute Tkinter
root.mainloop()
```

I thought I could just put the variables needed in the parentheses but it threw this error:

```
Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\Python\Lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 1948, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
TypeError: clicked() missing 2 required positional arguments: 'Apples' and 'AppleClickVal'
```

Comment: The code you posted can't give the error at the bottom of the question.

Comment: You have typo error Apples =+ AppleClickVal. Should be Apples += AppleClickVal

Comment: lbl.configure(text = "You just gained " + str(AppleClickVal) + " Apple! You now have " + str(Apples) + " apples!")
                                                                                                 ^^^^^^
UnboundLocalError: cannot access local variable 'Apples' where it is not associated with a value